# How to skip iteration in collection runner with data file in postman

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner

Is it possible to skip (or repeat once again) the iteration through the collection using JSON data file in the Collection Runner like:

```
    if(pm.environment.get("skip").to.eql("yes"){
      \\pm.iterationData.GOTOITERATION(2)  <--PSEUDOCODE
    }
```

I was thinking that if I would be able to access the whole datafile (array of objects), it will be possible to write such thing:

```
    var currentIterationData;
    function ChangeCurrentIteration(iterationNumber) 
{ currentIterationData =
data[iterationNumber] // here I want to access element of data's array
}
```

But don't I go in wrong direction? does my question have sence? thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify the question please? Not really sure what you mean by points 1 and 2, also not sure what you need to do with `data.toJSON()`

Comment: @DannyDaiton , 1: VariableScope is some king of  js objects in Postman Sandbox which represent's collection of Key:Value pairs, and has some methods(or functions, so you understand me). 2: I noticed that it is actually a JS object. so it makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah I understand what is it and how it works within the Postman application - What I don’t understand is how you would like to use it and your overall question. Is this a series of questions or one question? If there are more than 1, separate them out into their own question - you will be able to explain a single question in more detail and receive a prompt response.

Comment: @DannyDainton I just tried to rewrite the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with the below code:

```
var testID =pm.iterationData.get("testID");
if(testID.includes("<substring>")) {
    postman.setNextRequest(null);

};
```

Where the `"testID"` is one of the key value pair in data file and `pm.iterationData.get("key")` method retrieves the value. Based on the condition, the next request will be skipped and next iteration will continue. You could also repeat a particular request by adding:

```
postman.setNextRequest(<requestToRepeat>);
```

Comment: May you pls explain a little bit more.  If i understood correctly this solution doesn't give me an oppotrunity to "jump back" to iteration?

Comment: @BorysFursov - I suppose you wanted to 'repeat' a particular request with the same object (from an array of objects) until you get a desired outcome. If that is the case, you can repeat that request like this.`var res = JSON.parse(responseBody);
if (res.valueTocheck !== "expectedValue") {
    postman.setNextRequest("same_request");
}` This repeats with the same data until the outcome is received. please be aware you may get an error if the request us unsuccessful after three attempts.

Comment: thanks, but when will I have that error after  3 attempts? f.e.when there are `ReferenceError` whole run stops, what do you mean as unsuccessful request?

Comment: I meant the connection timeout error. Ive faced it before but worth trying that out. But I hope it answered your question.